# How to Use the JSON file in my HTML web page

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am trying to implement the following `JSON` file in my `HTML` page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> test get</title>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

      <script>
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('json.json',function(data) {
                $.each(data.quotes,function(key,value) {
                    alert( key+ "said by "+value);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the `JSON` that i am working on.

```
{
    "quotes": {
        "hey there":"randomguy1",
        "wassup":"randomguy2",
        "coool":"randomguy3"
    }
}
```

I have checked different tutorials and similar questions at stackoverflow still couldn't figure out the mistake.

Comment: are you getting a response? debugging json objects and seeing the "depth" or mistakes is pretty easy in the console

Comment: there may be error with your ajax request. and the rest of your code is correct. as it's running fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/z5fjfqx3/

Comment: Parse it into string before passing them into the alert function.
I hope this will work.

Comment: Or please tell me what you are getting, or how it's not working

Comment: You are missing closing tag of script

Answer (score 2):

Just fix your `script` code,

You **MUST** close the `<script ...jquery>` tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test get</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('json.json', function (data)
        {
            $.each(data.quotes, function (key, value) {
                alert(key + "said by " + value);
            });
        });

    });
  </script>

  </head>

  <body> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in a different manner. Use **ajax** to load a file content and parse it as a **json**.

```
$.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.json",
            success : function (data) {
                //TODO parse string to json
            }
        });
```